# Segue not transitioning to next view?

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode

I have been trying to figure this out for well over 3 hours now. After I successfully authorize my login with facebook, when the view tries to transition to the next view, it crashes with sigbart error: [4923:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key SegueToScene1.'

This is my segue to scene:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender  {
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    // Login PFUser using facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator
      if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueToScene1"
                                      sender: self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueToScene1"
                                      sender: self];
        }}];

    [_activityIndicator startAnimating]; // Show loading indicator until login is finished
}
```

**My question is, why does xcode keep refusing the segue?**

Edit: I deleted my segue and put a new one "SegueMain", then changed the code to reflect that, but strangely, it still returns the same error with SegueToScene1. How strange is this? There is no trace of that title left...anywhere. Yet, it remains...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have something connected in interface builder to perform the SegueToScene1 segue. To find it you could try searching the plain text version of your storyboard or you should probably have an idea of where it would be.